# trigger method not working in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom, dom-manipulation, jquery-events

I have a page which has about 100 divs like this.

```
<div id="ListItem_JBEEB_847">
  <span title="-HD">
      <span>F</span>
      <span style="pointer-events: none;">-HD</span>
  </span>
</div>
```

The IDs have different number. And I am trying to click on this div/or the spam via jQuery one by one. So, I made a loop like this..

```
$('div').each(function(){
     div = $(this).attr('id');
     if(div){
        if(div.includes('ListItem_JBEEB')){ 
            get_div = jQuery("#" + div).trigger('click'); 
         }
      }
});
```

The above code should work, but for some reason it doesn't. It works with styling and all other DOM manipulations like changing color of the text via 
`jQuery("#" + div).css({'color': 'red'})` so the loop is ok, I also tried to target the span using `jQuery("#" + div).find('span').trigger('click')` but nothing happens.

btw: on the website, if you click any of the divs, the instantly show you more information, but with the this nothing changes, I am not sure if the trigger click is even working

Comment: there are 2 spans in the div also do you have click event for which span you should be more specific in the selection of the span

Comment: I don't know if the spans trigger the effect, but I just click on the div ... there is no way to tell which element I am clicking on.. but I do click on the div and it works. If the spans had padding and there was a clear way to separate the spans from the div I would be able to know which el I am clicking on @guradio

Comment: @adeneo But I was able to simple create a test btn a new page and was able to click on the btn via `trigger()` ...

Comment: I deleted that comment, I have no idea what you're doing, but again, `trigger()` doesn't neccessarely do the same as clicking, it just triggers event handlers bound with jQuery.

Comment: As a sidenote you're entire code could be replaced by `$('div[id^="ListItem_JBEEB"]').trigger('click')`

Comment: I am trying to write a jquery code to let it click the btn so to speak. In don't want to click the button myself. like this code HTML `<form><input type='submit' class='foo'/></form>` and jQuery `jQuery('.foo').trigger('click')` this works, as in it clicks the submit button. I am trying to make the same thing, but to click the div @adeneo

Comment: The div IDs are in the 100s and they are different from eachother like `ListItem_JBEEB_343` upto `ListItem_JBEEB_454`... also, the loop allow me to alter or make some changes inside it

Comment: You can just write `$(this).trigger("click")`, you don't need to search for the ID when you have the element itself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the updated version of your code. Instead of `jQuery("#" + div).trigger('click')`, you can use `$(this).trigger('click')` and separately, define what should happen on the `click` event.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('div').each(function() {
    div = $(this).attr('id');
    if (div && div.includes('ListItem_JBEEB')) {
      $(this).trigger('click');
    }
  });
});

$('div').on('click', function() {
  console.log($(this).attr('id') + ' got clicked..');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="ListItem_JBEEB_847">
  <span title="-HD">
      <span>F</span>
  <span style="pointer-events: none;">-HD</span>
  </span>
</div>
<div id="ListItem_JBEEB_848">
  <span title="-HD">
      <span>F</span>
  <span style="pointer-events: none;">-HD-1</span>
  </span>
</div>
<div id="ListItem_JBEEB_849">
  <span title="-HD">
      <span>F</span>
  <span style="pointer-events: none;">-HD-2</span>
  </span>
</div>
```

Comment: +1 for the code. But I guess it should work, but for some reason it doesn't.  I opened the console and tried it on this website http://www.ephremtube.com/mp3.php and it does not open the folders

Answer (score 1):

You have to initialize the click event before calling it, You have to check that the particular click event is already initialized before calling it not not else it won't perform the click event.

**For Example**

```
// THIS WILL WORK
$(document).ready(function() {
    jQuery("#ListItem_JBEEB_847").click(function(){
        alert('a');
    });
    $('div').each(function(){
        div = $(this).attr('id');
        if(div){
            if(div.includes('ListItem_JBEEB')){ 
                jQuery("#" + div).click(); 
            }   
        }
    });
});

// THIS WILL NOT WORK
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('div').each(function(){
    div = $(this).attr('id');
    if(div){
        if(div.includes('ListItem_JBEEB')){ 
            jQuery("#" + div).click(); 
        }
    }
    });
    jQuery("#ListItem_JBEEB_847").click(function(){
        alert('a');
    });
});
```

Comment: +1 for the code. But I guess it should work, but for some reason it doesn't.  I opened the console and tried it on this website http://www.ephremtube.com/mp3.php and it does not open the folders